# USB device to be detected at the "same" /dev point always?

Tags: linux, shell-script, usb, devices, tty

In Linux *(actually I'm with CentOS v6.5)*, whenever I plug in my `USB Terminal/Character Device` *(some kind of USB Adapter)* for the first time (after booted), it is detected at:

```
/dev/ttyUSB0
```

But whenever I plug it OUT and IN again, it is again detected at:

```
/dev/ttyUSB1
```

The one and only same device.

That is making me problem with some configurations in my Applications.

- Meaning that sometime i am (i need to) plugging IN and OUT in **runtime**.

How do I make such USB Device *(which is first ever detected)* to be **always** detected at `/dev/ttyUSB0` (At "*Zero*" or whatever **always** at the **same** number.)

Comment: Would it not be a better approach to try and find the device by its ID and derive the `/dev` entry from that?

Comment: Could you give the USB drive a label and mount it via fstab on startup?

Comment: So this is not a drive right? Could you show us the output of `lsusb` when the adapter is connected? Why do you need the `/dev` name? WHat exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Anthon could you please advise "how to" do it please?

Comment: @夏期劇場 Each device has an ID depending on its manufacturer and function (e.g. `lsusb` can show it). Either change your applications to test `/dev/ttyUSB*` until it finds the ID, or have a script that creates a link on a fixed position to the `ttyUSB` found and have the program use that link.

Comment: You wil need to create a udev rule so that whenever your device is plugged in the same name is assigned. You can use `udevadm monitor` and plug your usb, identify your device and create the rule for udev.

Answer (score 1):

You can try via udev but it is not so easy, more found here, but be aware that the post is 4 years ahem lightyears old.
[USB devices not fixed on dev/sd? -> Fixed](https://www.clearos.com/clearfoundation/social/community/usb-devices-not-fixed-on-dev-sd-fixed)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a USB device using the pl2303 driver.
Every now and again /dev/ttyUSB0 would vanish and /dev/ttyUSB1 would appear in its place.

I solved it by running a cronjob every 15 minutes that did the following:

```
if [ ! -c /dev/ttyUSB0 ]
then
  echo `date` Device missing
  echo `date` Stopping zmconcopy `/usr/sbin/rczmconcopy stop 2>&1`
  sleep 2
  echo `date` Unloading drivers `/sbin/modprobe -r pl2303 2>&1`
  sleep 2
  echo `date` Reloading drivers `/sbin/modprobe pl2303 2>&1`
  sleep 2
  echo `date` Starting zmconcopy `/usr/sbin/rczmconcopy start 2>&1`
  echo `date` Finished
fi
```

It is important that any application that that uses /dev/ttyUSB0 is stopped before unloading the device driver.

You might be using a different driver than pl2303 so change this to whatever your driver is.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to use the device by the USB address (i.e. controller/hub and device number), like so:

```
ls -l /dev/bus/usb/0??/0??
```

You can find out the device number by using the `lsusb` command (try using it as root if you do not get all the information you need, albeit it usually tends to give you rather a lot of info), or use

```
udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyUSB0 --attribute-walk
```

Here is related information if you wish to dig a little further: https://askubuntu.com/questions/184526/how-to-get-bus-and-device-relationship-for-a-dev-ttyusb